# Facebook album thumbnails

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I'm trying to make photographs that work to the size of the Facebook album covers. I've found lots of information on the old photo size, but I can't find anything in the APIs or information sheets that lets me know either the size or the aspect ratio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the album covers that you're asking about are **FB Timeline covers**, the image dimensions are **851px by 315px** according to information on [this page](http://facebookcoversize.com/). The same information can be found at this [Time Techland article](http://techland.time.com/2012/02/23/an-easy-way-to-quickly-crop-your-facebook-timeline-cover-photo/).

Facebook has posted some information as well on this [help page](http://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=cover%20photo). The detailed specs include:

> **Cover images must be at least 399 pixels wide** and may not contain:
>
> - Price or purchase information, such as "40% off" or "Download it at our website"
> - Contact information, such as web address, email, mailing address or other information intended for your Page's About section
> - References to user interface elements, such as Like or Share, or any other Facebook site features
> - Calls to action, such as "Get it now" or "Tell your friends"
>
> To get the best quality image and fastest load times for your Page,
> **upload an sRGB JPG file** that's **851 pixels wide, 315 pixels tall and less than 100 kilobytes**.

**EDIT**:

If you're looking for the size of pictures in the photo album, [this site](http://www.dreamgrow.com/facebook-cheat-sheet-sizes-and-dimensions/) provides this spec:

> Pictures displayed in Facebook
>
> This is the maximum size of the image as shown in slide show or album.
>
> - Width: 960px
> - Height: 720px

The photo album cover would be governed by the same limitations, since from my understanding the cover image is just one of the images in the album.

Comment: I think (I’m not sure thou) the OP is talking about the covers of the album photos (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/eminem/photos_albums)

Comment: @alex, I've added some additional information to cover that possibility.